# Which metric use to see how separate are the distributions?

Tags: distributions, python, dimensionality-reduction, metric, tensorflow

I'm doing a dimension reduction, I would like to know which approach is separating better the classes, and How I can measure this?

I have two approaches:

How can I prove that my approach is separating 'better' than with **PCA** and How I can see which classes are more entangled with another.

P.s.: I don't want to use any classification metric. I need to know how I can compare each distribution and see how entangled(correlated) are they.

This My custom:

[image: custom dimension reduction]

And with PCA:

[image: PCA]

Comment: Have you considered the [silhouette coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)) ? also in general, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis)

Comment: @plumSemPy yes!!! That will do for now. Can you remember any method that is unsupervised?

Comment: I don't understand the question. These are metrics and they come into play after a clustering has happened. I assume you have done your clustering and now want to measure how well you are doing versus another method right?

Comment: @plumSemPy no. That's just a dimension reduction. I want to compare my method with pca. The only way is doing a clustering ? I'm wondering if there is any other method that I can measure the separation of the data.

Comment: your data points are colored, ie labeled, ie clustered already, right? so on each dimensionality reduced plane, you have a bunch of labeled data, now for each plane, using only those two dimensions, and using the colors as cluster labels, run a metric

Comment: @plumSemPy yes it's colored just because I used the training samples to fit and transform. That's why I know the labels. I want to take one distribution lets say 1 and compare how entangled is with 2. Than see how separate are each class. I need to perform a metric without the labels, just the distribution. The Silhouette is one example. I want to know more others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46213/discussion-between-plumsempy-and-alvaro-joao).